# Pass Parameter to Crystal Report in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I was trying to pass parameter from my code behind into my crystal report but I keep getting error

> Load Report Failed

I use dataset to pass the parameter to crystal report. My dataset has 1 column (Test1)

here is my code in code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~\Reports\CrystalReportTest.rpt")
        Dim rptDoc As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument
        rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("test", "test", "TestDB", "JulianPC", True)
        Dim a As String = "10001"
        Dim b As String = "10003"
        rptDoc.Load(path)
        rptDoc.FileName = "CrystalReportTest.rpt"
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("Test1", a)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
        CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

here is my aspx code

```
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="CrystalReportTest.rpt"></Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" AutoDataBind="True" HasPrintButton="True" HasRefreshButton="True" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" Height="50px" Width="350px"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: any help??need it urgent. I have tried googling it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to pass the parameters like this

```
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("parameter_name_as_String", "Value_as_String")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Dim RptDoc As New ReportDocument()
Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
Dim CrTables As Tables
Dim CrTable As Table
Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo

RptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/Reports/myReport.rpt"))

With crConnectionInfo
    .ServerName = "myServer"
    .DatabaseName = "myDatabase"
    .UserID = "myUserID"
    .Password = "myPassword"
End With

CrTables = RptDoc.Database.Tables

For Each CrTable In CrTables
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
Next 

RptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(crConnectionInfo.UserID, crConnectionInfo.Password, crConnectionInfo.ServerName, crConnectionInfo.ServerName)

RptDoc.SetParameterValue("@myParameter", myValue)

Dim stream As New BinaryReader(RptDoc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat))

Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & myDownloadAsFilename)
Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.BaseStream.Length.ToString())
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)))
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
```